# Select Axios React problema carga de data

Tags: reactjs, react-axios

Quiero cargar los datos de esta api en un select pero no lo logro, ya que no cuenta con un vaule o label y no se como insertar la data en el .map(), la data llega bien con axios o fecth pero luego no se como ingresarla al select, el plan es hacer selectsAnidados, me pueden ayudar?

https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincias.json

la documentacion de la API esta en esta pagina;

https://programando.paginasweb.cr/2016/04/29/lista-de-provincias-cantones-y-distritos-de-costa-rica-en-formato-json/

Estoy trabajando con React.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import axios from 'axios';


function SelectAxios() {


    axios.get(`https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincias.json`)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({ data:response.data})
        }

        )
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err); })



    



    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Axios</h1>
            <hr />


            
            <select name="provincias" className="form-control">
                <option>Elije una Provincia</option>
                {this.state.data.map(el => (
                    <option key={el} value={el}>{el.data}</option>
                )
                )
                }  
            </select>


        </div>
    )
}

export default SelectAxios
```

Este es el error que me devuelve en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La peticion esta bien pero la carga de la data en el select no se que problema tiene, me indica que es problema en el .map():

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas utilizando el setState, y en ningún momento tienes un state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás usando los [React Hooks](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), entonces no puedes usar la palabra reservada **this**.

Además, la manera en la que se utilizan los estados en esta nueva versión de React también varía en otras cosas.

## Solución propuesta

Para mostrarte su uso correcto, le hice varias modificaciones a tu código para conseguir lo que querías lograr.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function SelectAxios() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([" "]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincias.json`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response", Object.keys(response.data).length);
        let dataToArray = [];
        for (
          let index = 1;
          index < Object.keys(response.data).length;
          index++
        ) {
          console.log("response2");
          dataToArray.push(response.data[index]);
        }
        setData(dataToArray);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Axios</h1>
      <hr />

      <select name="provincias" className="form-control">
        <option>Elije una Provincia</option>
        {data.map((el) => {
          return (
            <option key={el} value={el}>
              {el}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SelectAxios;
```

[image: Edit new]

Puedes probarlo en *SandBox* y verificar si era lo que estabas buscando.

---

## Características del código

Ahora pasaré a explicar algunas características de este código.

Para empezar es el uso de los estados en esta versión de React.

Fíjate que se hace por medio de `useState`, lo que hace innecesario el uso del `this` a la hora de llamar un estado. El estado se llama como si de un objeto más se tratara.

Y lo mismo pasa al setear el estado. No es necesario el `this.setState()`, si no más bien se utiliza en este caso el `setData`.

Este `setData` es una función para modificar el estado cuyo nombre varía según lo que quieras ponerle, aunque por convención siempre tiene el mismo nombre del estado y la palabra "set" antepuesta.

Otra característica de este código es la manera en la que transformo en array los datos que vienen de la API:

```
let dataToArray = [];
        for (
          let index = 1;
          index < Object.keys(response.data).length;
          index++
        ) {
          console.log("response2");
          dataToArray.push(response.data[index]);
        }
        setData(dataToArray);
```

Lo que hice fue recorrer el objeto `data` del `response` con un bucle `for` que se repite por la cantidad de propiedades que tiene dicho objeto. La cantidad de propiedades que tiene el objeto de la respuesta se pueden contar con el `Object.keys(response.data).length`

Luego le voy haciendo `.push` al nuevo array que creé con `response.data[index]`. De esa forma puedo acceder a cada  una de las propiedades del objeto.

Finalmente actualizo el estado `data` con el nuevo array mediante el `setData()`.

Por último, la manera correcta de hacer el `.map` es utilizando el `return` por cada `<option>` del Select.

```
<select name="provincias" className="form-control">
        <option>Elije una Provincia</option>
        {data.map((el) => {
          return (
            <option key={el} value={el}>
              {el}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
```

Comment: Me sirvió muchas gracias. Estoy aprendiendo y todavia me falta pero muchas gracias por la explicacion aprendi bastante.